# CImg X11 Linking Error using CLion and CMake

Tags: c++, clion, cimg

I have a C++ project in CLion (Ubuntu) that uses the CImg library.  Currently, I cannot get the project to build properly.  I have included the CImg.h file in my main.cpp file.  I get an output like seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327727/cimg-library-linking-error).  I made sure I had X11 tools installed by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

In the question linked to above, there is an answer that states to add the following compiler options:

```
-L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11
```

However, I run into 2 problems with this. First, I am using CMake in CLion, not the command window, so I am not sure how to use this command (assuming it works).  Secondly, the path specified above does not seem to exist on my computer - there is no X11R6 folder within /usr. Therefore, how can I properly link the required X11 libraries so I may begin to use CImg?

(Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but I do not have Magick++ installed.)

Comment: CLion uses CMake build system. You may want to start with learning about it first.

Comment: @Drop I understand that CLion uses CMake. I have done some research (not a ton) into CMake, and it looks like target_link_libraries() may be what I am looking for, but I am not entirely sure.  Also, that is only one part of the problem (see post).

Comment: Do you actually want to display anything on X11? If not, `#define cimg_display 0` before including `CImg.h`.

Answer (score 10):

The way **CImg** programs need to be built is sadly not abundantly clear from the documentation. Here is my take on it:

**Step 1 - Do you need to display images on the screen?**

No, don't laugh, you may be manipulating images on a headless web server.

- If you do **NOT** need to display images, you must do `#define cimg_display 0` **before** you include `"CImg.h"`
- If you do need to display images, and you are on Windows, you need to link with `gdi32`
- If you do need to display images and you are on macOS, OSX, or Unix/Linux, you need to set the header include path for, and link with, X11

**Step 2 - Do you need to read/write PNG format images?**

- If you do **NOT** need this functionality, or if you are happy to let **CImg** use your already-installed **ImageMagick** to read/write PNG images, do nothing.
- If you want to use **CImg**'s built-in ability to read/write PNG images, you need to `#define cimg_use_png 1` **before** you include `"CImg.h"`, and you need to set the header include path for **libpng** and link with both `libpng` **and** `libz`.

**Step 3 - Do you need to read/write JPEG format images?**

- If you do **NOT** need this functionality, or if you are happy to let **CImg** use your already-installed **ImageMagick** to read/write JPEG images, do nothing.
- If you want to use **CImg**'s built-in ability to read/write JPEG images, you need to `#define cimg_use_jpeg 1` **before** you include `"CImg.h"`, and you need to set the header include path for **libjpeg** and link with `libjpeg`.

**Step 4 - Other stuff**

One further thing is that you *may* need to link with the maths and the POSIX threads library (using `-lm -lpthread` as linker switches), but I am not sure how to check that across all platforms, so I'll leave that to you - it can probably do no harm to add it.

---

So, bearing all that in mind, and using this little test program:

```
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {
    CImg<unsigned char> img(640,400,1,3);         // Define a 640x400 color image with 8 bits per color component.
    img.fill(0);                                  // Set pixel values to 0 (color : black)
    unsigned char purple[] = { 255,0,255 };       // Define a purple color
    img.draw_text(100,100,"Hello World",purple);  // Draw a purple "Hello world" at coordinates (100,100).
    img.display("Window Title");                  // Display the image in a display window.
    img.save_png("test.png");                     // Save as PNG to prove we linked correctly
    img.save_jpeg("test.jpg");                    // Save as JPG to prove we linked correctly
    return 0;
}
```

Your **CMake** `CmakeLists.txt` inside `CLion` will be something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(CImgProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(CImgProject ${SOURCE_FILES})

# You can alter these according to your needs, e.g if you don't need to display images - set(YOU_NEED_X11 0)
set(YOU_NEED_X11 1)
set(YOU_NEED_PNG 1)
set(YOU_NEED_JPG 1)

if(${YOU_NEED_X11} EQUAL 1)
    message(STATUS "Looking for X11...")
    find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(CImgProject ${X11_LIBRARIES})
else()
    target_compile_definitions(CImgProject PRIVATE cimg_display=0)
endif()

if(${YOU_NEED_JPG} EQUAL 1)
    message(STATUS "Looking for libjpg...")
    find_package(JPEG REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries (CImgProject ${JPEG_LIBRARY})
    target_compile_definitions(CImgProject PRIVATE cimg_use_jpeg=1)
endif()

if(${YOU_NEED_PNG} EQUAL 1)
    message(STATUS "Looking for libpng...")
    find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries (CImgProject ${PNG_LIBRARY})
    target_compile_definitions(CImgProject PRIVATE cimg_use_png=1)
endif()
```

Here is my, rather disappointing, image after all that!

[image]

Comment: Instead of `if(${YOU_NEED_X11} EQUAL 1)` it is better (and simpler) to check `if(YOU_NEED_X11)`. Also, variables `PNG_LIBRARY` and `PNG_INCLUDE_DIR` has been [obsoleted](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPNG.html) even in CMake 3.0. One should prefer `PNG_LIBRARIES` and `PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer did not work for me.  However, adding

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(My_Project Threads::Threads)

target_link_libraries(My_Project X11)
```

to my CmakeLists.txt worked to run the code from the link below from CLion.  I'm not experienced with CMake, so I can't explain it well (and cannot guarantee that it is optimal, but it does work).  I figured it out by seeing which flags were set in the instructions (http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__overview.html), figuring out which ones were unnecessary, and then figuring out how to add the necessary two (-lpthread and -lX11) to the CMakeLists file.

This is not a complete install solution; it adds what the other answers do not say. Before doing the above, don't forget to

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```