# Cannot load any image with CImg

Tags: c++, libjpeg, cimg

Any time I try to load an image I get an error saying `CImg<unsigned char>::load(): Failed to recognize format of file`. This happens for both jpg and png files.

I have found other posts about this saying to define `cimg_use_png` and `cimg_use_jpeg`, but then I get compilation errorstelling me I need `png.n` and `jpeglib.h`. Not sure where I'm supposed to get these from.

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, so I don't know what to ask specifically. What's gone wrong?

Comment: I didn't get it to work. I found a pre-compiled version of libjpeg, but once I set it up the original error (Failed to recognize format of file) came back. I switched over to stb_image in the end.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. What version of Windows are you using? And are you using Visual Studio - if so, which version?

Comment: Windows 10 and VS2017 Community. I also use the default empty C++ Solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to open `JPEG` images, you need to install `libjpeg` and compile and link against it.

If you want to open `PNG` images, you need to install `libpng` and `libz` (for the compression) and compile and link against them.

At the moment, you should be able to use NetPBM format images - i.e. PBM, PGM and PPM.

---

Well, after two painful days of trying to work out how on Earth **Visual Studio 2017** works, and how to install and integrate `libjpeg` with it, I can now explain how to install **CImg** and libjpeg on Windows.

**Step 1**

You need to have **Visual Studio 2017** installed, which means you need **Windows 7 with SP1** or better. When installing it, be sure to include *"Windows 8.1 SDK"*

[image]

**Step 2**

Download `libjpeg` from the [IJG website](http://www.ijg.org/files). I took `jpegsr9b.zip` as it is the latest.

[image]

**Step 3**

Unzip the file and store it in a directory called `libjpeg` in your HOME directory.

**Step 4**

Go to **Start>All Programs>Microsoft Visual Studio 2017>Visual Studio Tools > Developer Command Prompt for VS2017**

Navigate to the directory you just unzipped. That will be something like this:

```
cd libjpeg
cd jpeg-9b
```

**Step 5**

Now you are going to need to find a file called `win32.mak`. I found mine in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include`. Yours may be somewhere else if you have Windows 8.1 SDK. Anyway, wherever it is, you need to add its containing directory to your includes. So I did:

```
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include
```

**Step 6**

Now run `nmake` to get your SLN - some weird Microsoft *"solution"* file. The command is:

```
nmake -f makefile.vc setup-v10
```

And you should get a file called `jpeg.sln` - hurray!

**Step 7**

Now start **Visual Studio 2017**, and open the `jpeg.sln` file you just created and build the project. It will create a `Release` directory in your `libjpeg` directory and inside the `Release` directory you will find `jpeg.lib`. You have now installed `libjpeg`.

[image]

**Step 8**

Close that project, and start a new C++ command-line project and write your CImg-based program. I wrote the simplest ever:

```
#define cimg_use_jpeg
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main() {
    CImg<unsigned char> img("C:\\Users\\Mark\\test.jpg");
    img.display("Image");
    return 0;
}
```

**Step 9**

Download `CImg.h` from [Github](https://github.com/dtschump/CImg), and save it in a directory called `CImg` in your HOME directory.

**Step 10**

Now tell Visual Studio where the include files (for `CImg` and `libjpeg`) are and where the library files (for `libjpeg`) are:

[image]

**Step 11**

Now tell **Visual Studio 2017** that you want to link with `libjpeg`:

[image]

**Step 12**

Now you can compile, link and run your **CImg** program and load JPEG files and display them on the screen!

[image]

---

If you are using `cmake` on **Linux**/**macOS**, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41956016/2836621) shows you the way.

---

If you are compiling on **macOS** from the command line, you'll need to have **XQuartz** installed if you are display images on the screen, and you'll want something like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11  sample.cpp -o sample -I /opt/X11/include -L /opt/X11/lib -lX11 -ljpeg -lpng -lz
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with details on how to install and link with `libjpeg` in Windows.

Comment: I got stuck at step 5 - can't find `win32.mak` even though I have Windows 8.1 SDK installed.

Comment: @Draex_ I can never find anything on Windows either! Start a Command Prompt, and change directory to the top of your C: drive, with "cd \". Then try `DIR /B /S | FINDSTR /I win32.mak`

Comment: That command didn't find anything, but I've used a dll from this repo: https://github.com/amirhessam/libjpeg-windows and it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want CImg to work with jpeg or png images, you need to supply appropriate library.

Here's a tutorial how to install libjpeg to Visual Studio project. It's basically a 2019 update to Mark Setchell's answer.

**How to install libjpeg to your project**

1. Download [jpegsr9c.zip](http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsr9c.zip) (or newer) zip with source code
   [image: downloading jpeg source code]
2. Extract the archive to a folder.
3. Copy the address of the folder extracted from archive
   [image: folder from archive]
4. Search for *Developer Command Prompt* in Start menu
   [image: start menu search]
5. Navigate to extracted folder in Developer Command Prompt:

   > cd "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\temp\jpeg-9c"

Use right click to paste.

[image: changing directory]

6. Run this command:

   > NMAKE /f makefile.vs  setup-v15

[image: running nmake]

7. Open `jpeg.sln` (which was now created).

[image: new file]

8. In Solution Explorer, right click on the project. Select Retarget projects. Confirm prompt.

[image: retarget projects]

9. If you want to build your project for 64-bit platform: Right click on solution, select Configuration Manager and add new platform x64
   [image: select configuration manager]
   [image: new platform]
   [image: x64 platform]
10. Build solution

[image: build solution]

[image: build success]

11. Now let's move to your project with CImg. Create a folder jpeglib in your project (it's IncludedLibraries\jpeglib for me). And add it to `Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories` and to `Project Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories`
    [image: Additional Include Directories]
    [image: Additional Library Directories]
12. Add `jpeg.lib` to `Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

[image: Additional Dependencies]

11. Copy `x64/Release/jpeg.lib` to this folder.
12. Search for all header files (`*.h*) in jpeg project and copy them to this folder.

[image: all files]

13. Add `#define cimg_use_jpeg` before `#include "CImg.h"` in your project

[image: define cimg_use_jpeg]

14. All done! CImg is now able to read and save jpeg files.