# CImg doesn't recognize png/jpeg macOS

Tags: c++, macos, cimg

I'm new using, CImg I already installed CImg using `brew install cimg`, and then I installed XQuartz. When I'm trying to run this program in the terminal I get this error:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    CImg<unsigned char> A("img.png");
    A.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
[CImg] *** CImgIOException *** [instance(0,0,0,0,0x0,non-shared)] CImg<unsigned char>::load(): Failed to recognize format of file 'img.png'.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cimg_library::CImgIOException: [instance(0,0,0,0,0x0,non-shared)] CImg<unsigned char>::load(): Failed to recognize format of file 'img.png'.
```

And when I'm trying running the same code with `#define cimg_use_png 1` over the `#include "CImg.h"` I get [this](https://justpaste.it/61dxt) linker error

Solution:
This is the proper way to compile the file. `g++ -std=c++11  main.cpp -o main -I /opt/X11/include -L /opt/X11/lib -lX11 -ljpeg -lpng -lz`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055720/cannot-load-any-image-with-cimg)
And the `#define cimg_use_png 1` should be there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055720/cannot-load-any-image-with-cimg Visual Studio oriented, but basically if you want to load jpg or png you need to link with the appropriate libraries. This may help on a Mac. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903996/cimg-x11-linking-error-using-clion-and-cmake/41956016#41956016

Comment: @RetiredNinja that solved it, thanks.